# Curried function not getting called in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, currying, react-lifecycle

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.onRefresh(this.props.subdomainConfig)
}

onRefresh = config => () => {
    console.log('onRefresh', config)
}
```

In this react component the onRefresh function is not getting called at all when component mounts. If I use this function for RefreshControl then it is getting called.

```
<ScrollView
    refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this.onRefresh(this.props.subdomainConfig)}
        />
    }>
    <ZoneListComponent
        zones={zones}
        onPressEdit={this.onPressEdit}
    />
</ScrollView>
```

Appreciate if someone can tell me why this is not getting called in componentDidMount but works for RefreshControl.

Comment: `this.onRefresh(this.props.subdomainConfig)` returns a function, to invoke it you need an additional pair of parentheses at the end.

Comment: yup! understood that now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onRefresh` returns a function but doesn't call it.  Change that to

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.onRefresh(this.props.subdomainConfig)();
}
```